# How to relay incoming NetStream to outgoing

Tags: flash, actionscript, rtmp, netstream

Is it possible to make some kind of relay, to rebroadcast received stream to another host?
For example, if i have code like this

```
nsOut = new NetStream( outgoingNetConnection );
nsOut.client = {};
nsOut.addEventListener( NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus );       

nsIn = new NetStream( incomingNetConnection );
nsIn.client = {};
nsIn.addEventListener( NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus );
```

How to connect this two streams to make direct transfer from **nsIn** to **nsOut** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not possible within Flash. You might be able to solve it with a server, using for example Red5 to connect the incoming stream to an outgoing stream.